# restrain filter on get_the_excerpt to queried item in stead of current post

Tags: theme-development, filters, excerpt, code

So, I have a walker nav menu who add the page excerpt to all page links in the nav menu.

Now, I want to build a custom post excerpt for the blog archive.

All works fine when the nav menu doesn't meet the Blog Archive. On the blog archive the nav menu's excerpts get the filter of the blog archive. This is because the excerpt filter checks on the current post.

Is there a way for the excerpt filter to check on the queried item in stead of the current post? As with the walker menu...

**Here are the filters I use:**

For the walker menu

```
function q_menu_item_custom_output( $item_output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
    $excerpt_el = '';
    $p_id = $item->object_id;
    if ( has_excerpt( $p_id ) ) {
        $excerpt_el = '<span class="excerpt">' . get_the_excerpt($p_id) . '</span>';
    }
    return $item_output . $excerpt_el;
}
add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'q_menu_item_custom_output', 10, 4 );
```

and for the post excerpt:

```
function q_excerpt_custom( $excerpt ) {
    if ( get_post_type( ) == 'post' ) :
        $excerpt_custom = '<a class="card-permalink" href="' . get_permalink() . '" rel="nofollow">&nbsp; HA HA HA </a>';
        return $excerpt_custom;
    endif;
    return $excerpt;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'q_excerpt_custom' );
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the documentation for the `get_the_excerpt` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_the_excerpt/), we can see that it receives the `WP_Post` object representing either the current post or the post which was passed in to the `get_the_excerpt()` function call.

Thus,

```php
function q_excerpt_custom( $excerpt, $post ) {
    if ( get_post_type( $post ) == 'post' ) :
        $excerpt_custom = '<a class="card-permalink" href="' . get_permalink( $post ) . '" rel="nofollow">&nbsp; HA HA HA </a>';
        return $excerpt_custom;
    endif;
    return $excerpt;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'q_excerpt_custom', 10, 2 );
```